# How to disable local push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I though that iOS's local push notifications could be turned off by the user just the same way they do for the classic remote pushes...which is by going to the phone's Settings app, and the > Notifications > My_App_Name, and change the settings from there.

However, I have an app that only uses local pushes, and it's not listed there. Isn't there a way for the user to disable them, unless the developer has created a tailor made settings for that into the app?

Answer (score -1):

Disabling push notifications does not disable local notifications, they are independent of each other.

Comment: so should a developer implement his own "Disable notifications" options? No other way?

Comment: Yes, For local notifications, "Disable Notifications" should be implemented by the developer within the app itself and it can be turned ON/OFF by using app only not by the device setting as the path you have given.